# increase google cloud functions request size limit

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, body-parser

I am trying to write a [google cloud function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/) to upload build artefacts from my CI to google cloud storage, but I am getting hit by http error `413 Request Entity Too Large`.

The binary is about 64mb, and I suspect this error is due to size limit in  `body-parser` settings.

anyway to fix this to allow the function upload larger files?

Comment: hey did you get any work around

Comment: yeah, cloud functions put the raw http body in `req.rawBody` we took that and did with it whatever we wanted

Comment: `req.rawBody` didn't change anything for me :(

Comment: You may have used something else to disable automatic parsing ?

Comment: On my side, the error in cloud function logs was "too many parameters at queryparse". I fixed by JSON.stringify-ing one of my parameter that has lots of child nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it could be the Python virtual environment.
You can add the virtual environment directory (or any other directory that doesn't need to be uploaded) to the `.gcloudignoe` file, which behaves similarly to a `.gitignore` file. Everything that you specify on this file will not be uploaded to the cloud.